# getCurrentPosition lat/lng not translating to correct position in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, elm

I am having an issue using HTML5 Geolocation `getCurrentPosition()` and getting my actual location to show up with a marker in Google Maps. My application is written in Elm using the `elm-lang/geolocation` package to return my location with enableHighAccuracy turned on. There are no problems getting a lat/lng or with placing a marker at that lat/lng.

The problem I am having is that the marker on the map does not reflect my actual location. My accuracy is down to 12ft, and the marker when placed 10 times is consistently within a very small area of the map, however that very small area is about 90ft away from where I am standing. I cannot figure out if the issue is that the GPS location returned by my phone is just off from Google Maps' positioning, if my GPS is using some different type of scheme with which is displays the lat/lng coordinates, if geolocation does not interpret them properly, or if Google Maps just does not display markers in very precise GPS coordinates.

My application will be examining distances of less than 100ft, so a 90ft difference in placement of a marker is huge.

I am viewing the Google Map in satellite mode, if that makes a difference. Here is how the map is initialized.

```
window.roundsMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(ele),
                { zoom: 18
                , tilt: 0
                , mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                , center: coords
                , disableDefaultUI: true
                }
```

And here is how the marker is placed (myIcon is a js svg object created in another function):

```
 new google.maps.Marker({
            map: window.roundsMap,
            icon: myIcon,
            position: myPos
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to enable high accuracy ?

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    geolocationSuccess,
    geolocationError, {
        timeout: 0,
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge: Infinity
    }
);
```

source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions/enableHighAccuracy

You can also consistently watch the user position with watchPosition, results are generally more accurate :

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    geolocationSuccess,
    geolocationError, {
        timeout: 0,
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge: Infinity
    }
);
```

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition

Comment: Yes, "to return my location with enableHighAccuracy turned on," which does seem to give me a very good reading on GPS. When zoomed all the way in on the map, every tick I get is within a quarter inch of one another.  So the real example here is that I am standing at the end of my driveway with no trees or buildings in the way of me. I record 10 GPS ticks, and those all show up as on my front porch, all within 10ft of one another, but all nearly 100ft away from the end of the driveway.

Comment: And did you try to use `watchPosition` ?

Comment: I have used it, and it gives the same results.

Comment: Just to be sure the GPS is enable on your phone with wifi turned on ?

Comment: Yep, everything is on, and I would wait at least 5 minutes for the GPS to get set up before trying the readings to make sure at least a few satellites were linked. My getCurrentPosition is returning an accuracy of 12ft, which makes me think that it is connected well enough.  I haven't ruled out that my phone's GPS is just not that accurate, but is that normal that the accuracy would be that close, but the map would show a totally different placement of that position?